# Tizen emulator crashes with code c0000005

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-emulator

I am not able to start Tizen Emulator for platform wearable-3.0-circle-x86.
It crashes after the initial animation with the following details:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: emulator-x86_64.exe
  Application Version:  2.8.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    00000000
  Fault Module Name:    ig7icd64.dll
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4f830bee
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00000000008b84a9
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 1a0f
  Additional Information 2: 1a0fa670b6468291c71c7947450270f6
  Additional Information 3: 3123
  Additional Information 4: 31236a43732c9661446bc2d10d89c75b
```

Did I miss something obvious?

**Edit**
My dev PC is a Windows 7 sp 1 / 64 Bits / 16Gb Ram / Plenty of disk
Emulator version 2.5.55, build time 20170323-1510
So far I have tried the usual suspects : rebooting and reinstallling.

**Edit 2**
The bottom of emulator.log suggests a problem with my display driver

```
06:31:41.072|13612|I|      yagl| 688|[2197/2197] yagl_egl_wgl_config_enum:688 - WGL returned 12 configs, 12 are usable
06:31:41.584|14660|I|       ecs| 458|send suspend lock state : 1
06:31:41.584|14660|I|       hds| 333|hds status is 0, 
06:31:41.584|14660|I|       hds| 269|get_hds_list: 
06:31:41.584|14660|I|       hds| 318|none of mount candidates available.
06:31:41.639|14660|I|       ecs| 466|emuld connection is 1
06:31:41.947|14660|I|       ecs| 485|guest ip: 10.0.2.15
06:31:42.636|14660|I|       ecs| 477|set capabilities: 8191
06:31:42.637|14660|I|       ecs| 187|check_sensor_capability: 1fff
06:31:43.895|14676|I|net_helper| 329|Added new sdb client. ip: 127.0.0.1, port: 26097, serial: emulator-26101
06:31:43.895|14676|I|net_helper| 262|send 001ahost:sync:emulator-26101:0 to client 127.0.0.1
06:31:44.386|13612|I|      yagl| 688|[2518/2518] yagl_egl_wgl_config_enum:688 - WGL returned 12 configs, 12 are usable
06:31:45.255|13612|S| backtrace| 154|Exception occurred: Code[0xc0000005], Address[0x00000001808b84a9]
06:31:45.371|13612|I| backtrace| 138|#0000 0x00000001808b84a9 in ShInitialize from C:\Windows\system32\ig7icd64.dll
06:31:45.371|13612|I| backtrace| 138|#0001 0x00000001808ba082 in ShInitialize from C:\Windows\system32\ig7icd64.dll
06:31:45.371|13612|I| backtrace| 138|#0002 0x00000001808d7e2f in ShInitialize from C:\Windows\system32\ig7icd64.dll
06:31:45.372|13612|I| backtrace| 138|#0003 0x000000018037df91 in DrvSetCallbackProcs from C:\Windows\system32\ig7icd64.dll
06:31:45.372|13612|I| backtrace| 138|#0004 0x000000018023d8dc in DrvSetCallbackProcs from C:\Windows\system32\ig7icd64.dll
06:31:45.372|13612|I| backtrace| 138|#0005 0x0000000180242bb6 in DrvSetCallbackProcs from C:\Windows\system32\ig7icd64.dll
06:31:45.372|13612|I| backtrace| 138|#0006 0x000000000032173d in ???????? from E:\dev\tizen\studio\platforms\tizen-3.0\common\emulator\bin\emulator-x86_64.exe
06:31:45.373|13612|I| backtrace| 138|#0007 0x000000000031214e in ???????? from E:\dev\tizen\studio\platforms\tizen-3.0\common\emulator\bin\emulator-x86_64.exe
06:31:45.373|13612|I| backtrace| 138|#0008 0x00000000002f6604 in ???????? from E:\dev\tizen\studio\platforms\tizen-3.0\common\emulator\bin\emulator-x86_64.exe
06:31:45.373|13612|I| backtrace| 138|#0009 0x00000000002e9478 in ???????? from E:\dev\tizen\studio\platforms\tizen-3.0\common\emulator\bin\emulator-x86_64.exe
06:31:45.373|13612|I| backtrace| 138|#0010 0x000000000066a105 in ???????? from E:\dev\tizen\studio\platforms\tizen-3.0\common\emulator\bin\emulator-x86_64.exe
06:31:45.373|13612|I| backtrace| 138|#0011 0x000007fefe56415f in srand from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
06:31:45.374|13612|I| backtrace| 138|#0012 0x000007fefe566ebd in ftime64_s from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
06:31:45.374|13612|I| backtrace| 138|#0013 0x00000000778959cd in BaseThreadInitThunk from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
06:31:45.374|13612|I| backtrace| 138|#0014 0x0000000077aca561 in RtlUserThreadStart from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
```

Comment: Would you please share information about your development PC?

Comment: Please see edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!
Hardware GPU acceleration is apparently not supported by my Intel Graphics adapter.
Hence,

1. Open Emulator Manager
2. Edit Emulator settings
3. HW Support
4. Set GPU to OFF.
5. Start Emulator

I hope my 3 hours on this will save you time.

Comment: Still relevant on Windows 10. In my case installed with bootcamp on macOS. Since the VS Code extension didn't work, only development on Windows is really possible.